# formatting a text file into json by deleting comma

Tags: json, bash

I have to convert a text file into json format. The text file looks like this:

```
[  {
    "rule": "soi",
    "val": [
        {
            "abc": "OT01",
            "del": 15
        },
        {
            "abc": "OT11",
            "del": 15
        },
        {
            "abc": "OT20",
            "del": 15
        },

    ],
    "ion": "OT"
},
{
    "rule": "soi",
    "val": [
        {
            "abc": "UF01",
            "del": 15
        },
                    {
            "abc": "UF08",
            "del": 15
        },
     ],
    "ion": "UF"
},
{
    "rule": "soi",
    "val": [
        {
            "abc": "UO01",
            "del": 15
        },

        {
            "abc": "UO08",
            "del": 15
        },
        {
            "abc": "UO09",
            "del": 15
        },
        {
            "abc": "UO10",
            "del": 15
        },
        {
            "abc": "UO20",
            "del": 15
        },
     ],
    "ion": "UO"
} ]
```

So basically I want to remove the `,` just before the line `],`. Any ideas to do this in bash using `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: It's good that you posted the file you want to change, but [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins this is pretty much the file. It is all but JSON, excpet for those commas before "]," lines. I can do this in Java, but I want to do something short and sweet if possible. I can access & print just those lines using awk : awk '/]/ { print a } { a = $0}' inputfile but I don't know how to update the lines instead of printing.

Comment: Ahh, you say { print a >> "some_file.json"} and it will redirect the input from print to the file.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins Thanks, but the probelm with the redirect is that it only copies the output not the original file with the updates. I want to update only those lines with the comma in them i.e. remove that comma from the line just above "]," as that will make this file json.

Comment: Why not completely copy the file over to a temp file while removing the comma's. Delete (or rename) the old file and then rename the temp file to the original name.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins there are only certain commas that I want to remove. Not all the commas. I was looking for a solution like - find the line and update the line in the same file. Or read line by line - when line match happens (How to do this match?), remove the comma and read ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple `sed` script that can do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
:begin
$!{
   N
   bbegin
}
s/,(\s*\],)/\1/g
```

Use `chmod` to make it executable, then you can run it: `./sedscript myfile`.  Keep in mind that `sed` will not actually modify the file, just output the modified text to standard output, so you'll need IO redirection to collect the changes in a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about newlines, spacing and indentations, you can use a JavaScript interperter to do the job for you:

```
echo "print(JSON.stringify(" `cat jsonfile.txt` "));" | js | tee jsonfile.txt
```